# loopback __get__plural AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED

Tags: loopbackjs

Strongloop Loopback:

Can't get __get__plural to work on a hasMany relation to my user table. Failing with AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED.

version 2.27.0

```
  "relations": {
     "transactions": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "transaction",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
        },
      "acls": [
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "READ",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "ALLOW",
          "property": "__get__transactions"
        },
```

Here is the trace:

```
  loopback:security:role isInRole(): $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context principals: [] +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelName usr +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelId 57e75c6f1bc42b97d177db78 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context property __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context method __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessType READ +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   id "$anonymous" +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context getUserId() null +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() false +0ms
  loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:role isInRole(): $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context principals: [] +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelName usr +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelId 57e75c6f1bc42b97d177db78 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context property __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context method __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessType READ +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   id "$anonymous" +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context getUserId() null +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() false +0ms
  loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:role isInRole(): $owner +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context principals: [] +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelName usr +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelId 57e75c6f1bc42b97d177db78 +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context property __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context method __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessType READ +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   id "$anonymous" +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context getUserId() null +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() false +0ms
  loopback:security:role Custom resolver found for role $owner +0ms
  loopback:security:role isOwner(): usr 57e75c6f1bc42b97d177db78 userId: null +0ms
  loopback:security:role isInRole(): admin +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context ---AccessContext--- +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context principals: [] +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelName usr +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context modelId 57e75c6f1bc42b97d177db78 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context property __findById__transactions +1ms
  loopback:security:access-context method __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessType READ +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context accessToken: +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   id "$anonymous" +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context   ttl 1209600 +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context getUserId() null +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context isAuthenticated() false +0ms
  loopback:security:role isInRole() returns: false +0ms
  loopback:security:acl The following ACLs were searched:  +2ms
  loopback:security:acl ---ACL--- +1ms
  loopback:security:acl model usr +0ms
  loopback:security:acl property * +0ms
  loopback:security:acl principalType ROLE +0ms
  loopback:security:acl principalId $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:acl accessType * +0ms
  loopback:security:acl permission DENY +0ms
  loopback:security:acl with score: +0ms 7495
  loopback:security:acl ---ACL--- +0ms
  loopback:security:acl model usr +0ms
  loopback:security:acl property * +0ms
  loopback:security:acl principalType ROLE +0ms
  loopback:security:acl principalId $everyone +0ms
  loopback:security:acl accessType * +0ms
  loopback:security:acl permission DENY +0ms
  loopback:security:acl with score: +0ms 7495
  loopback:security:acl ---Resolved--- +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context ---AccessRequest--- +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  model usr +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  property __findById__transactions +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  accessType READ +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  permission DENY +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  isWildcard() false +0ms
  loopback:security:access-context  isAllowed() false +0ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing from the plurals ACL:

"principalType": "ROLE"

Answer (score 1):

The ACL log shows that loopback is evaluating the access request for the property `__findById__transactions`.

However, in your `acls` definition, you allowed access for property `__get__transactions`. Thus, replace `__get__transactions` by `__findById__transactions`.

IMHO, the names for remote methods can be sometimes tricky and rather inconsistent.

Comment: Good comment, a better solution, but already tried and won't work without my accepted solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, no problem. In fact, both answers are needed right ? Did you generate the acl using the command line or wrote it manually ? Glad you solved your issue anyway